# Resharper Ajax setting unsafe header

Tags: javascript, resharper, user-agent, sinon, chutzpah

I'm getting a javascript exception from something being set up in ResharperAjax.cs, but can't figure out how to get around it

The lines that seem to be causing the issue in ResharperAjax.cs are:

```
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "ReSharperTestRunner 7.0");
```

The setRequestHeader method is resulting in an exception (Refused to Set unsafe header - User Agent).

It happens when I try to run some basic JS unit tests using Chutzpah and Sinon.js.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is fixed already in 8.0 EAP, build with this fix included will be available shortly.

Here are related issues in ReSharper's bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-337989 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-363233